# php fills $_POST data instead of php://input

Tags: php

There is strange behavior of the php work. I pass json data via POST and expect that data appear in `php://input`.Instead of it fills $_POST with the strange key/value pairs. Here is curl call

```
$process = curl_init("https://www.myurl.com/script");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);


$params = '{"Response":{"Data":{"RMID":"0910403545","QID":"965102499460","RspCode":"000","RspDesc":"Successful Transaction Complete","TrxID":"61801","TrxStatus":"COMPLETE","BID":"61801","TrxRC":"4201","TrxTime":"2015-06-15 14:53:51","TrxValue":"9"}},"Signature":"5bf094adb23e40e1de135c055684dd2098ab18d0","Certificate":"-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

5bf094adb23e40e1de135c055684dd2098ab18d0
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.5 (GNU/Linux)

iD8DBQFVfoSPQ8sozXgiBRURArdkAKCwx5ggf5dE+djAAMIDsHaapLRgOACePyys
a5scG9GhRFDefGz5CLHrqfI=
=AWpR
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
"}';

curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$return = curl_exec($process);
```

And on other end I get

```
echo "<pre>";
var_export($_POST);
---------------------------------------------
array (
  '{"Response":{"Data":{"RMID":"0910403545","QID":"965102499460","RspCode":"000","RspDesc":"Successful_Transaction_Complete","TrxID":"61801","TrxStatus":"COMPLETE","BID":"61801","TrxRC":"4201","TrxTime":"2015-06-15_14:53:51","TrxValue":"9"}},"Signature":"5bf094adb23e40e1de135c055684dd2098ab18d0","Certificate":"-----BEGIN_PGP_SIGNED_MESSAGE-----
Hash:_SHA1

5bf094adb23e40e1de135c055684dd2098ab18d0
-----BEGIN_PGP_SIGNATURE-----
Version:_GnuPG_v1_4_5_(GNU/Linux)

iD8DBQFVfoSPQ8sozXgiBRURArdkAKCwx5ggf5dE_djAAMIDsHaapLRgOACePyys
a5scG9GhRFDefGz5CLHrqfI' => '
=AWpR
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
"}',
)
```

Why does it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);`

> This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array. ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php))

cURL is expecting a param/value pair, and you've supplied just a string, so cURL assumes the *parameter* is everything up to the first `=` sign, and the *value* is everything after that until the first `&` sign is encountered, which there aren't any. That is why `$_POST` looks this way when you dump it.

One way to alleviate this is to urlencode the `$params` string and pass it into `curl_setopt` like `"data=".rawurlencode($params)`, then retrieve it using `rawurldecode($_POST["data"]);`.